# gdal python gdal_calc function not giving same results as command line

Tags: python, gdal, raster-calculator, gdal-calc

I have an interpolated file which looks like this

[image]

The Z values in it are positive, so I want to use `gdal_calc` to make them negative.
This works on the command line with

```
gdal_calc -a interpolated.tif --outfile gdal_negative.tif --calc="-abs(-a)"
```

[image]

based on this, I wanted to incorporate this into a python script so have done it with `subprocess` as follows (please note that the interpolated tiff seen above is already stored in the variable `interpolated_file`:

```
print('Pre calc')
        negative_file = output_file + '_negative.tif'
        calculation = '--calc=-abs(-a)'
        subprocess.call(['gdal_calc.py', '-a', interpolated_file, '--outfile', negative_file, '--overwrite', calculation])
        print('Post calc')
```

This runs ok, no errors thrown. HOWEVER, the result is this

[image]

why is the top of the raster blank when there's data?! It's also the exact same command as the command line