# Python subprocess not recognising gdalwarp option

Tags: python, gdal, gdalwarp

I have been trying to use the `subprocess` module in python to perform the `gdalwarp` command.

To do so, I have done it like so

```
# use pixel size for GDAL WARP command
print('Pre warp')
warped_file = output_file + "_warped.tif"
subprocess.call(['gdalwarp', negative_file, warped_file, '-te', extent, '-tr', pixelsize])     
print('Post warp')
```

However, I keep getting this error

```
ERROR 6: Unknown option name '-te'
Usage: gdalwarp [--help-general] [--formats]
    [-s_srs srs_def] [-t_srs srs_def] [-to "NAME=VALUE"]* [-vshift | -novshift]
    [[-s_coord_epoch epoch] | [-t_coord_epoch epoch]]
    [-order n | -tps | -rpc | -geoloc] [-et err_threshold]
    [-refine_gcps tolerance [minimum_gcps]]
    [-te xmin ymin xmax ymax] [-tr xres yres] [-tap] [-ts width height]
    [-ovr level|AUTO|AUTO-n|NONE] [-wo "NAME=VALUE"] [-ot Byte/Int16/...] [-wt Byte/Int16]
    [-srcnodata "value [value...]"] [-dstnodata "value [value...]"] -dstalpha
    [-r resampling_method] [-wm memory_in_mb] [-multi] [-q]
    [-cutline datasource] [-cl layer] [-cwhere expression]
    [-csql statement] [-cblend dist_in_pixels] [-crop_to_cutline]
    [-if format]* [-of format] [-co "NAME=VALUE"]* [-overwrite]
    [-nomd] [-cvmd meta_conflict_value] [-setci] [-oo NAME=VALUE]*
    [-doo NAME=VALUE]*
    srcfile* dstfile

Available resampling methods:
    near (default), bilinear, cubic, cubicspline, lanczos, average, rms,
    mode,  max, min, med, Q1, Q3, sum.
```

Why is not recognising `-te` when its explicitly stated as an option??

Comment: Try making your extent arguments a single space separated string `[etc..., '-te', ' '.join(map(str, extent)), etc...]` or `[etc..., '-te', ' '.join([f'{xy}' for xy in extent])), etc...]`  Assuming of course that your `extent` var is a simple list or tuple of coordinates `[xmin, ymin, xmax, ymax]`.

Answer (score 3):

A simple test with gdalwarp executable

```
gdalwarp -te
ERROR 6: Unknown option name '-te'
```

Another test

```
gdalwarp -te 1 2 3
ERROR 6: Unknown option name '-te'
```

And one more

```
gdalwarp -te 1 2 3 4
Usage: gdalwarp [--help-general] [--formats]
...
```

So it is possible to make the ERROR 6 to appear. by using `-te` option without giving  the four terms `xmin ymin xmax ymax`. Check how you pass on the "extent" in your code `subprocess.call(['gdalwarp', negative_file, warped_file, '-te', extent, '-tr', pixelsize])`

Comment: I am passing four parameters, thats why I'm confused. ```gdalwarp negative_file warped_file -te 626025.04 231749.32 628094.65 234200.73 -tr 0.2816945692119213 0.28160941987363625```

Comment: Are you sure that you pass them right so that all four terms are kept together?

Comment: Anyway I do not  believe that people should run gdalwarp with Python via subprocess because there is the Python library alternative. See usage examples from the GDAL autotests https://github.com/OSGeo/gdal/blob/master/autotest/utilities/test_gdalwarp_lib.py

Comment: It was out of curiosity I wanted to try it because I am getting this result with the Python library https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/441920/gdal-python-gdal-calc-function-not-giving-same-results-as-command-line

Comment: I believe that this current question is more a generic Python question, but have you tried to pass `'-te', 'xmin', 'ymin', 'xmax', 'ymax']`? I apologize that I am not good at Python, usually just copying what I find from stackexchange.